# Starting a TCP socket thread with Gunicorn

Tags: python, python-3.x, gunicorn

Say I have threads like this in `__main__`:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    t1 = threading.Thread(target = flaskThread)
    t2 = threading.Thread(target = tcpServerThreader)
    t1.daemon = False
    t2.daemon = False
    t1.start()
    t2.start()
```

When I start this and use ngrok, the tcpThread works, but when I try to deploy with Gunicorn it doesn't.

Comment: whats the exception you get?
where does it fail?

Comment: That's the problem, it does not show anything